# MySQL: get all references to another scheme

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, database-schema

**I have:** Two schemes `scheme1` and `scheme2`.

**I want** To delete something from `scheme1`.

**Problem:** `scheme2` have dependencies on `scheme1` so I can't delete what I want.

**Question:** Is there a way to print all dependencies in `scheme2` to `scheme1`? How to do that?

**Question2:** It would be perfect if you know how to get ALL dependencies on `some_table` from all schemes. Do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for second question, if it's tables that are dependent on "some_table":

```
select TABLE_NAME 
from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
where REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = <some_table>
```

of the other way around:

```
select REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME 
from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
where TABLE_NAME = <some_table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you by dependency mean foreign key you can check that in:

```
select * from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS;
```

Comment: what about not only foreign keys, but also View's dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question already had a good answer. If you are in MySQL 5.0 you can use `information_schema.table_constraints` else if you are in 5.1 or higher you can use `information_schema.referential_constraints`.

See this thread here from `dbo.stackexchange.com`

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5441/how-to-find-dependencies-on-a-table-in-mysql-5-0

By your second query if you mean find dependencies of a table, I think you can just use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
```

which will list out all foreign key constraint defined for a particular table.

Comment: seems SELECT * FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS works only in boundaries of current schema. I didn't see any table from schema1 in REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME when I launched this script in shema2. Do you know why?

Comment: @V_B, that's not true. all referenced table will be present irrespective of their schema. Look carefully.

Comment: yes, you're right. Know I know that there are many View dependencies

Comment: @V_B, sorry but didn't understood. are you asking another question?

Comment: no, I've already find the way: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.VIEWS WHERE TABLE_NAME = some_name AND TABLE_SCHEMA = some_schema`;